# recompiling linux kernel always ending with desktop manager not working

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, kernel, crash

I've tried recompiling the linux kernel, modified and not modified, but it always shows me an error.
With LightDM: systemd load modules failed to find nvidia-nvsm
And with SDDM: failed to read number from pipeline

I don't know a lot about linux so I just followed the tutorial here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel/Traditional_compilation

For the installation of Arch I just used archinstall, I tried Budgie (LightDM) and KDE Plasma (SDDM).
I've tried using nvidia-dkms instead of nvidia but that still didn't work out. If there are any logs I could give, please let me know.

I’m using Arch 5.19-rc6 and nvidia-dkms. (The error is the same on every self compiled kernel)

lsmod | grep nvidia output:

```
nvidia_modeset       1425408  19 nvidia_drm
nvidia_uvm           2740224  0
nvidia              45367296  1139 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
```

And here's the boot log: https://pastebin.com/ecQGxW8x
And when running journalctl with: -p 3 -xb those are the errors that I get:

```
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.SADX], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.SADS], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.RDLY], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14._DSM], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.BTRT], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14._PRR], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.BRDY], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.BRDS], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.ECKY], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.ECKV], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.GPCX], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.GPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.BTLY], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS14.BTLC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
Jul 12 13:19:54 jenusis systemd-modules-load[441]: Failed to find module 'nvidia-uvm'
Jul 12 13:19:59 jenusis sddm[553]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Jul 12 13:20:01 jenusis kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
Jul 12 13:20:01 jenusis sddm[553]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Jul 12 13:20:04 jenusis sddm[553]: Failed to read display number from pipe
Jul 12 13:20:04 jenusis sddm[553]: Could not start Display server on vt 1
```

The first errors aren't important as much as I know. It's just about the: systemd-modules-load[441]: Failed to find module 'nvidia-uvm'

And when I run modinfo nvidia-uvm that's the message I get:

```
modinfo nvidia-uvm
filename:       /lib/modules/5.18.10-arch1-1/updates/dkms/nvidia-uvm.ko.zst
supported:      external
license:        Dual MIT/GPL
srcversion:     3170E1233D7C787ABE15CDF
depends:        nvidia
retpoline:      Y
name:           nvidia_uvm
vermagic:       5.18.10-arch1-1 SMP preempt mod_unload 
parm:           uvm_ats_mode:Set to 0 to disable ATS (Address Translation Services). Any other value is ignored. Has no effect unless the platform supports ATS. (int)
parm:           uvm_perf_prefetch_enable:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_prefetch_threshold:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_prefetch_min_faults:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_thrashing_enable:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_thrashing_threshold:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_thrashing_pin_threshold:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_thrashing_lapse_usec:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_thrashing_nap:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_thrashing_epoch:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_thrashing_pin:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_thrashing_max_resets:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_map_remote_on_native_atomics_fault:uint
parm:           uvm_disable_hmm:Force-disable HMM functionality in the UVM driver. Default: false (i.e, HMM is potentially enabled). Ignored if HMM is not supported in the driver, or if ATS settings conflict with HMM. (bool)
parm:           uvm_perf_migrate_cpu_preunmap_enable:int
parm:           uvm_perf_migrate_cpu_preunmap_block_order:uint
parm:           uvm_global_oversubscription:Enable (1) or disable (0) global oversubscription support. (int)
parm:           uvm_perf_pma_batch_nonpinned_order:uint
parm:           uvm_cpu_chunk_allocation_sizes:OR'ed value of all CPU chunk allocation sizes. (uint)
parm:           uvm_leak_checker:Enable uvm memory leak checking. 0 = disabled, 1 = count total bytes allocated and freed, 2 = per-allocation origin tracking. (int)
parm:           uvm_force_prefetch_fault_support:uint
parm:           uvm_debug_enable_push_desc:Enable push description tracking (uint)
parm:           uvm_debug_enable_push_acquire_info:Enable push acquire information tracking (uint)
parm:           uvm_page_table_location:Set the location for UVM-allocated page tables. Choices are: vid, sys. (charp)
parm:           uvm_perf_access_counter_mimc_migration_enable:Whether MIMC access counters will trigger migrations.Valid values: <= -1 (default policy), 0 (off), >= 1 (on) (int)
parm:           uvm_perf_access_counter_momc_migration_enable:Whether MOMC access counters will trigger migrations.Valid values: <= -1 (default policy), 0 (off), >= 1 (on) (int)
parm:           uvm_perf_access_counter_batch_count:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_access_counter_granularity:Size of the physical memory region tracked by each counter. Valid values asof Volta: 64k, 2m, 16m, 16g (charp)
parm:           uvm_perf_access_counter_threshold:Number of remote accesses on a region required to trigger a notification.Valid values: [1, 65535] (uint)
parm:           uvm_perf_reenable_prefetch_faults_lapse_msec:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_fault_batch_count:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_fault_replay_policy:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_fault_replay_update_put_ratio:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_fault_max_batches_per_service:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_fault_max_throttle_per_service:uint
parm:           uvm_perf_fault_coalesce:uint
parm:           uvm_fault_force_sysmem:Force (1) using sysmem storage for pages that faulted. Default: 0. (int)
parm:           uvm_perf_map_remote_on_eviction:int
parm:           uvm_exp_gpu_cache_peermem:Force caching for mappings to peer memory. This is an experimental parameter that may cause correctness issues if used. (uint)
parm:           uvm_exp_gpu_cache_sysmem:Force caching for mappings to system memory. This is an experimental parameter that may cause correctness issues if used. (uint)
parm:           uvm_channel_num_gpfifo_entries:uint
parm:           uvm_channel_gpfifo_loc:charp
parm:           uvm_channel_gpput_loc:charp
parm:           uvm_channel_pushbuffer_loc:charp
parm:           uvm_enable_va_space_mm:Set to 0 to disable UVM from using mmu_notifiers to create an association between a UVM VA space and a process. This will also disable pageable memory access via either ATS or HMM. (int)
parm:           uvm_enable_debug_procfs:Enable debug procfs entries in /proc/driver/nvidia-uvm (int)
parm:           uvm_peer_copy:Choose the addressing mode for peer copying, options: phys [default] or virt. Valid for Ampere+ GPUs. (charp)
parm:           uvm_debug_prints:Enable uvm debug prints. (int)
parm:           uvm_enable_builtin_tests:Enable the UVM built-in tests. (This is a security risk) (int)
```

It says that it's in the modules folder, but in the 5.18.10-arch1-1 folder, I'm pretty sure that I have to somehow make nvidia-uvm be found with the new kernel, but I just don't know how.

Comment: If you have an nvidia card, the nvidia driver has to load for the desktop to work correctly.  Either you are not recompiling the nvidia driver after recompiling the kernel, or you are doing something that prevents it from compiling or loading.  Even using the wrong kernel version could cause this.  And you didn't include either the nvidia driver version, which packaging method it uses, or which kernel version you are trying to compile.

Comment: The same version arch linux uses, 5.18.10

Comment: and about the nvidia recompiling; i’m using nvidia-dkms and as much as i know it automatically does the work for new kernels.

Comment: Put these comments into your question.  Also, show the output from `lsmod | grep nvidia`

Comment: just did that @user10489

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to just uninstall nvidia-dkms and install it once the kernel is installed into the system.

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure of the nvidia module would also do that.